# How do you justify the strange behaviour of Edward in Nocturnal Animals?

Tags: plot-explanation, nocturnal-animals

In Nocturnal Animals, why didn't Tony, the protagonist of Edward's story, show any anger when he saw the rapists? He didn't even show much grief on his wife and daughter's death.

Moreover, he didn't look too interested to find the rapists. Was it to show that Edward isn't interested now to get his wife back after she left? But a part of him which he framed as the cop Bobby Andes wants to know the reasons why his wife left and wants to get her back.

As I understood it Edward's main motive was to take revenge on his wife who cheated on him because he was weak. But I struggle to understand how Tony's behaviour figures into the bigger picture there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why didn't Tony, the protagonist of Edward's story, show any anger
>   when he saw the rapists

Susan told Edward that he is weak we know that from the night they broke up, he told her that she already told him "He is weak" before. That's why Edward made Tony's personality as weak in the novel. This even becomes more clear when Ray tells him he is weak, but then Tony shoots him. We can match this with Edward's life, Susan would be Ray, she told him he is weak, but at the end he got his revenge by making a great novel about himself, sending it to her and proving he was a great writer then not showing up at the restaurant at the end of the movie.

> He didn't even show much grief on his wife and daughter's death.

I disagree with that, he was very sad about his wife and daughter's death, we can see that when he sat crying in the bathroom as well as in some other scenes when he meets the criminals. Or maybe because of his weak personality we can't notice this.

That's all my opinion based on how I saw the movie.

Answer (score -2):

> Why didn't Edward show any anger when he saw the rapists?

Because this whole story did not happen! It's his fictional book.

PS. It wasn't Edward whose wife and daughter were killed, it was Tony.

Comment: Well, yeah, I don't doubt the asker is aware of that. But that doesn't invalidate the question. So why didn't *Tony* show any anger when he saw the rapists then?